# Android google maps activity with marker created in place where user clicked

Tags: android, android-activity, maps

I'm writing a application in android, I know how to get a geolocalization of user but I couldn't find any example where that user after click on map showed where he is.
I need a activity with Google Maps and when user clicked on map (showed where He is) then marker is created (then I can obtain Latitude and Longitude where He clicked).
I couldn't find any example with this case, anyone can help me??
Code which create a marker but defaultly (not after click user):

```
   mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .snippet("Lat: " + myLocation.getLatitude() + ", Lng: " + myLocation.getLongitude())
            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
            .title("You are here!")
            .flat(true)
            .draggable(true));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `setOnMapClickListener` on your `GoogleMap` object:

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .snippet("Lat: " + point.getLatitude() + ", Lng: " + point.getLongitude())
            .position(point)
            .title("You are here!")
            .flat(true)
            .draggable(true));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @asadmshah will test it on evening